# More Pythonic to write Functions with Regex

Tags: python, regex

I've got 20'000+ court documents I want to pull specific data points out of: date, document number, verdict. I am using Python and Regex to perform this.

The verdicts are in three languages (German, French and Italian) and some of them have slightly different formatting. I am trying to develop functions for the various data points that take this and the different languages into regards.

I'm finding my functions very clumsy. Has anybody got a more pythonic way to develop these functions?

```
def gericht(doc):
    Gericht = re.findall(
        r"Beschwerde gegen [a-z]+ [A-Z][a-züöä]+ ([^\n\n]*)", doc)
    Gericht1 = re.findall(
       r"Beschwerde nach [A-Za-z]. [0-9]+ [a-z]+. [A-Z]+ [a-z]+ [a-z]+[A-Za-z]+ [a-z]+ [0-9]+. [A-Za-z]+ [0-9]+ ([^\n\n]*)", doc)
    Gericht2 = re.findall(
       r"Revisionsgesuch gegen das Urteil ([^\n\n]*)", doc)
    Gericht3 = re.findall(
       r"Urteil des ([^\n\n]*)", doc)
    Gericht_it = re.findall(
       r"ricorso contro la sentenza emanata il [0-9]+ [a-z]+ [0-9]+ [a-z]+ ([^\n\n]*)", doc)
    Gericht_fr = re.findall(
       r"recours contre l'arrêt ([^\n\n]*)", doc)
    Gericht_fr_1 = re.findall(
       r"recours contre le jugement ([^\n\n]*)", doc)
    Gericht_fr_2 = re.findall(
       r"demande de révision de l'arrêt ([^\n\n]*)", doc)

    try:
       if Gericht != None:
          return Gericht[0]
    except:
          None

    try:
       if Gericht1 != None:
           return Gericht1[0]
    except:
          None

    try:
       if Gericht2 != None:
           return Gericht2[0]
    except:
          None

    try:
       if Gericht3 != None:
           return Gericht3[0]
    except:
       None

    try:
       if Gericht_it != None:
           return Gericht_it[0]
    except:
       None

    try:
       if Gericht_fr != None:
           Gericht_fr = Gericht_fr[0].replace('de la ', '').replace('du ', '')
           return Gericht_fr
    except:
       None

    try:
        if Gericht_fr_1 != None:
            Gericht_fr_1 = Gericht_fr_1[0].replace('de la ', '').replace('du ', '')
            return Gericht_fr_1
    except:
        None

    try:
       if Gericht_fr_2 != None:
           Gericht_fr_2 = Gericht_fr_2[0].replace('de la ', '').replace('du ', '')
           return Gericht_fr_2
    except:
        None
```

Comment: what is an expected input for the regex, you mentioned a document, can you give an example document

Comment: If this is **working code** that you think could be improved, consider [codereview.se]. But note that you could just put the various `Gericht`s in a list, and iterate over it. Also `try:` with a bare `except:` is very much an antipattern (http://blog.codekills.net/2011/09/29/the-evils-of--except--/), and `pass` is better than just having a random `None`.

Comment: Here some [example files](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/17t0lvyii89pbay/AADLO1y6bwg0ZRoRGK3aPPnoa?dl=0) does this help?

Comment: Why should I use `pass` instead of `None`?

Comment: because [None](https://docs.python.org/2/library/constants.html#None) is a constant and `pass` is an actual statement

Comment: Note: Doubling `\n` in `[^\n]` makes no difference.

Comment: Where are you pulling out "date, document number, verdict"? Where are they in the patterns?

Answer (score 0):

The result of `re.findall()` is *never* `None`, so all those `if` statements testing this are superfluous.  Then using `findall()` when you just want the first result does not make sense.

The replacing in french results may remove too much.  For instance the `'du '` replacement does not just remove the word *du* but also affects words *ending* with *du*.

```
def gericht(doc):
    for pattern, is_french in [
        (r'Beschwerde gegen [a-z]+ [A-Z][a-züöä]+ ([^\n]*)', False),
        (
            r'Beschwerde nach [A-Za-z]. [0-9]+ [a-z]+. [A-Z]+ [a-z]+'
            r' [a-z]+[A-Za-z]+ [a-z]+ [0-9]+. [A-Za-z]+ [0-9]+ ([^\n]*)',
            False
        ),
        (r'Revisionsgesuch gegen das Urteil ([^\n]*)', False),
        (r'Urteil des ([^\n]*)', False),
        (
            r'ricorso contro la sentenza emanata il [0-9]+ [a-z]+ [0-9]+'
            r' [a-z]+ ([^\n]*)',
            False
        ),
        (r"recours contre l'arrêt ([^\n]*)", True),
        (r'recours contre le jugement ([^\n]*)', True),
        (r"demande de révision de l'arrêt ([^\n]*)", True),
    ]:
        match = re.search(pattern, doc)
        if match:
            result = match.group(1)
            if is_french:
                for removable in [' de la ', ' du ']:
                    result = result.replace(removable, ' ')
            return result

    return None
```